# c++ boost::thread() in Qt application - error: too many arguments to function

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am trying to integrate the functionality of boost::thread in my Qt applications but the compiler produces an error. I am **not** new to boost::thread, as a matter of fact I have used it many, many times in non-qt applications but for some reason I am having issues with this one. Here is the exact code:

header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <QMainWindow>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
      explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
      ~MainWindow();

   private:
      Ui::MainWindow *ui;

      static void my_lengthly_method();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

source file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

   boost::thread(&my_lengthly_method, this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::my_lengthly_method()
{

}
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

LIB_GLOBAL = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS  

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

LIBS += \
   -L$$LIB_GLOBAL -lboost_system \
   -L$$LIB_GLOBAL -lboost_filesystem \
   -L$$LIB_GLOBAL -lboost_thread \
   -L$$LIB_GLOBAL -lboost_regex
```

I run the project and:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:259: error: too many arguments to function
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When you click on the error, it opens up that file and here is what you get:
[image]

I have used this awesome library in many different non Qt projects before and I have never had any issues. Is there any work around for this?

All of my APIs are based around boost::thread.

I can use Qt threads but I don't want to.

Anyway, right now, I want to get the boost thread thing to work.

Comment: Try with `boost::thread(boost::bind(&my_lengthly_method, this));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_lengthly_method` is static method so `this` is redundant, just call

```
    boost::thread(&my_lengthly_method);
```

In above line you create a temporary thread object and after executing this line the thread temporary object is destroyed, in this place you may have problem because in C++ standard library when destructor of `std::thread` is called without calling `join` on it `std::terminate` is called - your app is closed. In BOOST it depends on how your library was built, if with define `BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE` then your code will work. But for safe you should name your object and call `deatch` method.

```
     boost::thread myThread(&my_lengthly_method);
     myThread.detach();
 }
```

Comment: @marko If you have static function with prototype `foo(int,double)` you pass parameters after pointer to function member so call `thread th(&foo,10,3.34f)`, when you want to call non-static member you should put `this` between pointer to function and paremeters so call `thread th(&foo,this,10,3.34f)`. Read about `boost::ref` / `boost::cref` if you want to pass objects of classes as parameters.

Comment: rafix07, about passing non-static member functions, when I try to do that, I get `ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function` so I that's why I opted for: `static void my_lengthly_method(MainWindow *wnd);`in class declaration and then `boost::thread(&my_lengthly_method, this);` works as expected and in `my_lengthly_method, *wnd);` I can do what I want. That's a work around because I have failed passing non-static member functions to boost:thread. If any one knows how this is done, please advise. Thx

Comment: @marko ohh my mistake, you have to put `&ClassName::functionMember`, so call `&MainWindow::my_lengthly_method`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That works for methods that don't take parameters, for instance, this compiles fine: `void foo();` and then `boost::thread(&MainWindow::foo);` but the following fails: `void foo2(int);` and `boost::thread(&MainWindow::foo2, 10);`  - I want to pass 10 to foo2 and fails with: `/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:333: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_pointer(const int&)’` - I would appreciate if you can assist with this too.

Comment: @marko It seems `foo2` is non-static member so `this` is missing, call `thread(&MainWindow::foo2,this,10)` .

Comment: Well done! Thank you, today I learned something! Until now, I have been using static methods like I have shown with passing the address of the class as a work around with boost::tread because I was unable to figure out the correct syntax. This is awesome!